# Youtube API for IOS (search functionality)

Tags: xcode, youtube, ios8

I want the users of my app to be able to search videos on YouTube and play whatever they may choose. However, all the open source code I've seen requires the video identifier to stream it. Is there a way I can use the YouTube search engine to browse and play videos?